# How do I get the user of a mentioned user in an option? discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a bot that's trying to kick a mentioned user in the slash command but when I mention a user in the "user" option it says `User not found` and gives an error of `x is not a valid function` (x is whatever I'm trying). I'm trying to find a valid function to actually define the user mentioned but can't seem to find one. Any help is appreciated since I am new to javascript and discord.js

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, OptionType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('tkick')
    .setDescription('Kicks the specified user by tag (Moderation)')
    .addMentionableOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName('user')
        .setDescription('The user to be kicked')
        .setRequired(true),
    ),

  async execute(interaction, client) {
    if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(['KICK_MEMBERS']))
      return interaction.reply(
        'You do not have permission to use this command.',
      );

    // Get the user from the interaction options
    const user = interaction.user;
    if (!user) return interaction.reply('User not found.');

    // Kick the user
    await interaction.option.('user').kick(); // This is where I am having the issue

    // Reply with the text
    await interaction.reply({
      content: 'User has been kicked.',
    });
  },
};
```

I tried looking at different questions I looked up but it's either in an older version where it isn't there or got removed. Discord.js v13 got released in December 2022 but I can only find posts before that.

Comment: discord.js v13 was released in August 2021. And you can't kick a `User` only a `GuildMember`, it's been answered many, many times on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interaction.option.('user').kick()` is not a valid syntax and `interaction.user` is not a `GuildMember`, but a `User` object. To be able to [kick someone](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick), you need a `GuildMember` object which can be obtained by using the `interaction.options.getMentionable` method if you use `addMentionableOption`.

However, it accepts roles and users. If you don't want your bot to accept mentions of roles, which would make your life a bit more difficult, it's better to use the `addUserOption` instead of `addMentionableOption`. With `addUserOption`, you can get the `GuildMember` object by using the `interaction.options.getMember` method:

```js
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('tkick')
    .setDescription('Kicks the specified user by tag (Moderation)')
    . addUserOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName('user')
        .setDescription('The user to be kicked')
        .setRequired(true),
    ),

  async execute(interaction) {
    if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(['KICK_MEMBERS']))
      return interaction.reply(
        'You do not have permission to use this command.',
      );

    try {
      await interaction.options.getMember('user').kick();
      interaction.reply('User has been kicked.');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(error);
      interaction.reply('⚠️ There was an error kicking the member');
    }
  },
};
```